# Vector of 16bit Integers

Tags: integers

I would like to define a vector $\mathbf{s} = [s_1, \ldots, s_N]^{\operatorname{T}}$ with length $N$ where each element is a 16bit two's complement signed integer (in C one would write `int16_t si = 0;` for a scalar 16bit integer and `int16_t s[N] = {0};` for a vector).

A single element is thus $s_i \in \{x\in\mathbb{Z} \mid -2^{K-1} \leq x \leq 2^{K-1}-1\} = \{x\in\mathbb{Z} \mid -32768 \leq x \leq 32767\}$ with $K=16$ being the number of bits.

What I would write for the vector is $\mathbf{s} \in \{x\in\mathbb{Z} \mid -2^{K-1} \leq x \leq 2^{K-1}-1\}^N$.

But is there a more elegant way?

How do I, in an elegant and compact way, define a vector $\mathbf{a} \in A^N$, where A is set defined by me?

Comment: Before going any further, your notation is abysmal. What does $\{x: P(x)\}^N$ even mean? In simple terms, what you have so far doesn't make sense. 1: you can't exponentiate sets. 2: if you **really** want to factor $N$ into the set somehow, you will have to do it within the braces.

Comment: That was supposed to be the vector notation. Just like you would write $\mathbb{R}^N$ for an N-dimensional real vector. But this is exactly what I am struggling with. The exponent is supposed to be a shorthand notation for applying the cartesian product a certain amount of times.

Comment: $\mathbb R ^n$ is a set of n-tuples: $\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n):x_i\in \mathbb R, 1\leq i \leq n\}$

Comment: As an electrical engineering student, I am used to seeing the terms tuples and vectors being used equivalently. So per your notation, I would simply have to replace the $\mathbb{R}$ by my definition of the set of all 16bit integers? So replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $A$ and define $A = \{x\in\mathbb{Z} \mid -2^{K-1} \leq x \leq 2^{K-1}-1\}$?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent. In general, an $m×n$ matrix is notated as an element of $\mathbb R ^ {m×n}$. In this case you can indicate $A^k$ or however many tuples you require.

Comment: Okay, but this brings me back to my set notation from above, right? Because $A=\{...\}$ and thus $A^N=\{...\}^N$.

Comment: Why not $\mathbf{s} \in \{(x_1,\dotsc,x_N)\in\mathbb{Z}^N \mid x_i\in A, 1\le i\le N\}$?

Comment: @rogerl Yes, that would certainly work too. But then I would have to define two sets (yours and $A$). I am also having trouble understanding what the problem with the $\{...\}^N$ notation is?

Comment: It's unconventional. @rogerl 's answer seems pretty elegant. Look, you will necessarily have to define two seperate sets you can't just combine them without explicating the properties picked out by each set.